# Why does my function returning long long, returns 705032704?

Tags: c++, loops, decimal, long-integer, radix

I'm working on a code that returns the value in base 10 for a given string and base. But for large values of numbers in base 10, my program just returns 705032704 instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

    int val(char c)
    {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            return (int)c - '0';
        else
            return (int)c - 'A' + 10;
    }

            long long basemachine(int base, char *str) {         //this function returns answer in base 10
            int len=strlen(str); int power=1; long long num=0;

           for (int i=len-1; i>=0; i--) {
              num+= val(str[i])*power;
              power=power*base;
           }
           return num;
         }

int main() {
    char str1[]="2P6X2MU";
    char str2[]="6PMP5GK";
    long long n=basemachine(35, str1);
    long long m=basemachine(30, str2);
    cout<<n<<" "<<m;
    return 0;
}
```

(2P6X2MU) base 35 and (6PMP5GK) base 30 both = 5000000000 
But my code is returning 705032704 705032704 instead of 5000000000 5000000000 
How do I fix this?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: `power` is of type `int` instead of `long long`.

Comment: I have tried this program for smaller values and it works fine @NathanOliver , I don't get why it won't return long long value

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes I tried `power` of type `long long` as well, still getting the same problem

Comment: @P.Pawar -- Why are you not printing out the intermediate values to see where the issue is?  You haven't done the least bit of debugging, from what I am seeing.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, my bad

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but note that `c - 'A' + 10` is not required to do anything meaningful. It "works" **if** the codes for the characters `A ..Z` are contiguous and increasing. That is not required by the language definition, and there are character sets (such as EBCDIC) where this is not the case. `c - '0'`, on the other hand, **is** required to work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

`power` is of type `int` instead of `long long`.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/WfD3Yi)

Comment: So all I had to do was that, thanks. I tried keeping it as long long but my program didn't build correctly. Now it's working fine